# How to Encrypt/Decrypt in dio cache interceptor flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dio

does anyone know how to use the cipher functionality in dio cache interceptor package for flutter?

```
final options = const CacheOptions(
  store: MemCacheStore(),
  policy: CachePolicy.request,
  hitCacheOnErrorExcept: [401, 403],
  maxStale: const Duration(days: 7),
  priority: CachePriority.normal,
  cipher: null,
  keyBuilder: CacheOptions.defaultCacheKeyBuilder,
  allowPostMethod: false,
);
```

if someone can just show me a simple code snippet with methods of encrypt and decrypt that I can use on this package. that would be amazing. Thankyou